# Using two different tables in a JavaScript step

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I have 2 different tables (2 fields and 3 fields) from the same access file and I want to use them in a JavaScript Step but send me a hop error

I use join steps but one multiply the rows and the others ask me for a foreign key.

I would like to use the data from the 2 different tables in the javaScript step.[image][image][image]

enter image description here

Comment: Do the data sets have keys on which to join on ? Or they are completely distinct informations ?

Comment: they are completely distinct informations.. One have date data types and the other have int data types

Comment: merge two steps first then take it to java_script

Comment: What is the information you're trying to formulate with these 2 sets of data ? You need a Key on wich to join all the rows, otherwise all you have is a clump of useless information.

Comment: i just add two photos of my tables and the data type..... is it good if i join "Antiguedad" and "Identificador"?

Answer (score 0):

It is totally possible for to hops to target the same step (a Javascript in your case), and you do not have to do any thing special to "union" flows.

Except that the **two flows must be strictly similar** : columns in the same order with the same name and the same type. You can use two `Select value` steps for that.

Something you hate when you develop and love when you maintain.